# Rotating image with uneven image width and height

Tags: java, image, rotation, graphics2d

I am trying to rotate an image having uneven width and height say : 890W 180H ... works fine for (512X512) or (72x72)

The Below Code works perfectly for an image with equal height and width. If i rotate the same on the paintComponent() the image would rotates fine, but it causes issue with image panning. Can someone provide me with an alternative way to rotate the image without using 'g.rotate()' on paintComponent(), or at-least help me to understand how rotation is performed on an image with unequal width and height

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImageHolder extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
  BufferedImage image;
  int imageX = 0, imageY = 0;
  int parentWidth, parentHeight;

  public ImageHolder() {}


  public ImageHolder(BufferedImage image) {
    this.image = image;
    setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    parentWidth = this.getWidth();
    parentHeight = this.getHeight();
    imageX = (this.getWidth() - image.getWidth())/2;
    imageY = (this.getHeight() - image.getHeight())/2;
    addMouseListener(this);
 }

 @Override
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(image, imageX, imageY, (int) image.getWidth(), (int) image.getHeight(), null);
 }

 @Override
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    rotate(Math.PI / 2);
    repaint();
 }

 private void rotate(double d) {
    BufferedImage clonedImage =new BufferedImage((int) this.image.getWidth(), (int) this.image.getHeight(),this.image.getType());
    Graphics2D g2d = clonedImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.rotate(d, clonedImage.getWidth() / 2, clonedImage.getHeight() / 2);
    g2d.drawImage(this.image, null, 0, 0);
    g2d.dispose();
    this.image = clonedImage;
}


@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following series of commands to get a working transform:

```
g.translate(newCenterX, newCenterY);
g.rotate(d);
g.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
```

where `centerX/Y` are the coordinates of the original center and `newCenterX/Y` are the coordinates of the new center. Note that rotating by 90° swaps the images width/height and thus also their centerX/Y coordinates. That means the following:

```
Rotation    X    Y
0°          X    Y
90°         Y    X
180°        X    Y
270°        Y    X
360°        X    Y
```

So the `newCenterX/Y` depend on the value of `d`